# Find the minimum speed of a yo-yo, revolving in a vertical circle, so that the cord does not slacken

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A yo-yo is swung with a constant speed in a vertical circle. If the yo-yo has a mass of 80 g and the radius of the circle is 1.5 m, find the minimum speed that this yo-yo must have at the top of the circle so that the cord does not slacken.

Answer (score 3):

If the Yo-Yo string doesn't slacken, the centrifugal force at the top is greater than or equal to the force exerted due to the weight of the Yo-Yo (mass of string is considered negligible here). Only then there is some tension in the string to prevent it from slackening.

\begin{align}\require{cancel}\cancel{m}\,\frac{v^2}{r} &\ge \cancel{m}g\\ \frac{v^2}{r} &\ge g\\ v &\ge\sqrt{gr}\end{align}

$m$: mass of the Yo-Yo, $v$: velocity at highest point,

$r$: vertical radius of the circle (or length of the string) and $g$ is acceleration due to gravity.

Since you are looking for minimum speed, we can take minimum value of $v$ , that is

$\sqrt{gr}=\sqrt(9.8\times1.5)=3.83\large\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{sec}}$

which is basically independent of the mass of the yo-yo.